# Finding duplicate array in 2d array and adding number to tuple

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

I have an array :

```
 a = [[(1,2), (3,4)], [(4,5),(3,4)]]
 # Stores list of x,y coordinates
```

and an array:

```
 b = [(1,2), (3,4)]
```

Now, I want to replace in `a` where it has an equivalent of `b` with y coordinate + 2.

Since here `a` has an equivalent of `b` in:

```
[(1,2), (3,4)]
```

I want to replace in `a` such that it becomes:

```
a = [[(1,4), (3,6)], [(4,5),(3,4)]]
```

How could I do this?

I know there exists a method with numpy such that:

```
np.where(a == b) , do something;
```

but not sure how could I use it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With numpy

```
a[(a==b).all(1).all(1),:,1] +=2
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about good solution in `numpy` for this, but you can go with list comprehension instead:

```py
>>> a
[[(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(4, 5), (3, 4)]]
>>> b
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
>>> c=[[(el_inner[0], el_inner[1]+2) for el_inner in el] if el==b else el for el in a ]
>>> c
[[(1, 4), (3, 6)], [(4, 5), (3, 4)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

**main():**

```
def main():
    a = [[(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(4, 5), (3, 4)]]
    b = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]

    for i, el in enumerate(a):
        if el == b:
            temp = []
            for x in el:
                c = (x[0], x[1]+2)
                temp.append(c)

            a[i] = temp
    print(a)
```

**output:**

```
[[(1, 4), (3, 6)], [(4, 5), (3, 4)]]
```